# A nav pill is selected (active), but the content is not displayed. How come?

Tags: html, jquery, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

So I want to create one page for different types of users. That is, instead of creating a view for ADMIN, another view for USER, I want to have one view for both and hide certain elements from those who lack the ADMIN privilege. I wrote this code

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<!-- ... -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-1 px-2 pt-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">
                    <a th:class="'nav-link' + ${loggedUser.isAdmin() ? ' active' : ''}" data-toggle="pill" href="#admin-tab">Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a th:class="'nav-link' + ${!loggedUser.isAdmin() ? ' active' : ''}" data-toggle="pill" href="#user-tab">User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11 p-0 tab-content">
             <div id="admin-tab" class="tab-pane container mw-100 p-0"...>
             <div id="user-tab" class="tab-pane container p-0 mx-auto" th:object="${loggedUser}"...>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When this code gets to a browser, it turns into this (if I log in as an ADMIN)

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-1 px-2 pt-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#admin-tab">Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#user-tab">User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11 p-0 tab-content">
            <div id="admin-tab" class="tab-pane container mw-100 p-0">
                <!-- the admin tab content -->
            </div>
            <div id="user-tab" class="tab-pane container p-0 mx-auto">
                <!-- the user tab content -->
            </div>
```

Cool, huh? The problem

[image]

Interestingly, I can click the User tab and then re-click the Admin tab, and the content gets displayed

[image]

Mickey Mouse can't do even that since he doesn't have a tab to re-click from

[image]

It's as if JS cares only about manual clicks whereas CSS is fine with `active` attributes too

I noticed that they [use](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_pills_toggleable&stacked=h) `role="tablist"` with Bootstrap 4 on *w3schools*. However, including that element didn't help

**Why isn't my tab content displayed right away? How do I get it fixed?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mw-100">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-1 px-2 pt-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#admin-tab">Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#user-tab">User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11 p-0 tab-content">
            <div id="admin-tab" class="tab-pane container mw-100 p-0">
                <p class="text-center">Admin tab content</p>
            </div>
            <div id="user-tab" class="tab-pane container p-0 mx-auto">
                <p class="text-center">User tab content</p>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wonder what else I can do to get this answered ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `#active-tab` an `active` class, and it will display its content by default, and so the problem is solved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mw-100">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-1 px-2 pt-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#admin-tab">Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#user-tab">User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11 p-0 tab-content">
            <div id="admin-tab" class="tab-pane container mw-100 p-0 active">
                <p class="text-center">Admin tab content</p>
            </div>
            <div id="user-tab" class="tab-pane container p-0 mx-auto">
                <p class="text-center">User tab content</p>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool! So I have to assign the `active` class to both the button and the table, don't I? Why isn't it enough to just have an `active` button (that, in turn, triggers the tab)?

Comment: * I meant "tab", not "table"

Comment: Yes, because it's that plain, it's just not determined by the script.